# How to undo already synced github commits in vscode?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, github, commit

I have tried to search for the answer, everything i find is either not the same problem or the answer is very vague and not explained well. I am using vscode, when i was pushing my changes to git hub, i clicked the "COMMIT & SYNC" button. well i found out that i committed the wrong file, now i tried to undo the commit thinking it was as straight forward as that but then its not acting like i thought it would.

first of all this "incoming and outgoing" tab appeared now it wont go:

[image]

it shows the commits i tried to undo but then it wont go away indicating that the commits havent been undone and there is a problem somewhere. Also now when i try and "COMMIT AND SYNC" another change it gives me this error:

[image]

Look, you dont need to tell me that i fucked up, i know i shouldnt have synced the changes at once, but surely there is a way to fix this? Please answer like i am 5 years old if its possible.

Comment: ("*Gerard it is bed time now, be a good boy.*" Just kidding.) It would be precious here to know what the "Commit and sync" feature is supposed to do. "Sync" is not part of the git lexicon. Commit and *push*?

Comment: im not sure, all i know is that when i commit a change, it doesnt automatically show the change on my github till i sync it, so i guess it is used to show the changes on your github profile

Comment: @gerard Then we can infer that it is referring to a "push" when it says, "sync." I can help you solve your problem by giving you a few commands, but if you're set on only using VS Code's interface, then I'm not sure.

Comment: @gerard If you want to use commands, then open your Git terminal to the directory of your repository. **Only do this if the last commit you made was the one that you didn't mean to make.** Type the exact following two commands in the displayed order: `git reset HEAD~`, `git push -f`. At this point, your problem will be solved.

Comment: @gerard And don't worry, `git reset HEAD~` is a mixed reset, which means you won't lose anything. It just gives you the chance to "undo" the mistake commit in the remote, so it will look like it was never there.